# Master not pods in NotReady status

Tags: kubernetes

In my single master Kubernetes 1.15 cluster, some of the pods shows in NotReady status. some pods in Ready and in NotReady status?

How to clean up pods in NotReady status?

```
 # crictl pods 
POD ID              CREATED             STATE               NAME                                       NAMESPACE           ATTEMPT
7ddfd0ce6c7ea       8 hours ago         Ready               kube-proxy-vntzl                           kube-system         0
e430a86591d26       8 hours ago         Ready               calico-kube-controllers-65b8787765-rrlwv   kube-system         3
e4d6510396731       8 hours ago         Ready               coredns-5c98db65d4-gbplj                   kube-system         2
07b7eda330c7d       8 hours ago         Ready               kube-apiserver-master01                   kube-system         3
9310330074be8       8 hours ago         Ready               etcd-master01                             kube-system         3
929ea8dc9580c       8 hours ago         Ready               kube-scheduler-master01                   kube-system         3
3fb1789729499       8 hours ago         Ready               calico-node-h422j                          kube-system         3
b833585489625       8 hours ago         Ready               kube-controller-manager-master01          kube-system         3
4aef641d05712       8 hours ago         NotReady            calico-kube-controllers-65b8787765-rrlwv   kube-system         2
69f4929fe0268       8 hours ago         NotReady            coredns-5c98db65d4-gbplj                   kube-system         1
10536cc6250ee       8 hours ago         NotReady            kube-scheduler-master01                   kube-system         2
7b7023760c906       8 hours ago         NotReady            calico-node-h422j                          kube-system         2
180fba7f48d86       8 hours ago         NotReady            kube-controller-manager-master01          kube-system         2
d825333e0a833       8 hours ago         NotReady            etcd-master01                             kube-system         2
5d9d9706458d8       8 hours ago         NotReady            kube-apiserver-master01                   kube-system         2
```

Thnaks

Comment: I would first suggest to check why some pods are NotReady. Try to find the reason using `kubectl describe podname -n namespace` also check the logs using `kubectl logs podname -n namespace`. In case you want to right away delete those pods use `kubectl delete pod podname -n namespace`

Comment: @mchawre I was able to remove the NotReady pods using this command `crictl rm  4aef641d05712`

Comment: @sfgroups Feel free to provide an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to remove NotReady pods using `crictl` command.

```
crictl pods|grep NotReady|cut -f1 -d" "|xargs -L 1 -I {} -t crictl rmp {}
```

Comment: Much simpler: `crictl rmp $(crictl pods -q --s NotReady)`

Comment: crictl throws this when I try to remove using `rmp`: `removing the pod sandbox "b0ea9676affc4": rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded`